# ASP.NET Parser Error Cannot load code behind

Tags: asp.net

Hey I am getting the following error

Parser Error
Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: Could not load type '_AddToCart'.

Source Error:

```
Line 1:  <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" Codebehind="AddToCart.aspx.cs" Inherits="_AddToCart" Title="Untitled Page" %>
Line 2:  
Line 3:  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">


Source File: /FSAICart/AddToCart.aspx    Line: 1
```

Where I do have the matching code behind file which is defined as follows

```
    using System;
  public partial class _AddToCart : System.Web.UI.Page {
```

Any Ideas ?

Comment: Make sure the underscore appears everywhere.

Comment: Generally its a best practice to have same name to both the class and the file.try cleaning the solution and building again.

Comment: got rid of the underscore but still get error Could not load type 'AddToCart'. <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="True" Codebehind="AddToCart.aspx.cs" Inherits="AddToCart" Title="Untitled Page" %>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specify the namespace of the `Inherits` property of `Page` directive

Look at codebehind of your page. It looks like:

```
namespace MyWebSite
{
     public partial class _AddToCart : System.Web.UI.Page 
     {
        //...
     }           
}
```

So you must change `Page` directive to:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" Codebehind="AddToCart.aspx.cs" Inherits="MyWebSite._AddToCart" Title="Untitled Page" %>
```

Comment: Sorry not to sure what you mean there can you give an example i.e here <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="True" Codebehind="AddToCart.aspx.cs" Inherits="AddToCart" Title="Untitled Page" %>

Answer (score 26):

Try changing **CodeBehind**:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#"
AutoEventWireup="true"
**Codebehind**="AddToCart.aspx.cs"
Inherits="_AddToCart" Title="Untitled
Page" %>
```

To **CodeFile**:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#"
AutoEventWireup="true"
**CodeFile**="AddToCart.aspx.cs"
Inherits="_AddToCart" Title="Untitled
Page" %>
```

ASP .NET 1.1 used **CodeBehind** for compiling code in a separate file. ASP .NET 2.0 introduced the **CodeFile** syntax for compilation of partial classes.

See [here](http://mjjames.blogspot.ca/2008/02/so-what-is-it-code-behind-or-code-file.html) for a more detailed explanation.