# Parser Error Message: Could not load type in Default.aspx

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to load Default.aspx from my browser. I am getting the following message.

My aspx file has the following initial snippet,

```
<%@ Page Language = "C#" AutoEventWireup = "false" Inherits = "xxxxxxxx.Default" ValidateRequest = "false" EnableSessionState = "false" %>
```

The suggested answer talks about changing codebehind to codefile. I have a codebehind file, but I don't know how to change it to codefile.

My code behind is a lengthy one. If you prefer, I could post it here.

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Parser Error Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a
>   resource required to service this request. Please review the following
>   specific parse error details and modify your source file
>   appropriately.
>
> Parser Error Message: Could not load type 'xxxxxxxx.Default'.

Source Error:

```
Line 1:  <%@ Page
Line 2:     Language           = "C#"
Line 3:     AutoEventWireup    = "false"

Source File: /default.aspx    Line: 1
```

My codebehind,

```
/*
  `* Created by SharpDevelop.` 
  `* User: WELCOME` 
  `* Date: 8/13/2018` 
  `* Time: 5:08 PM` 
   * 
   * To change this template use Tools | Options | Coding | Edit Standard 
   Headers.
   */`
   `using System;`
   `using System.Collections;`
   `using System.ComponentModel;`
   `using System.Data;`

   using System.Drawing;


using System.Web;
using System.Web.SessionState;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;

namespace SandLogin
{
     /// <summary>
     /// Description of MainForm.
    /// </summary>`
    public class Default : Page
    {   
    //<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    #region Data

    protected   HtmlInputButton     _Button_Ok;
    protected   HtmlInputText       _Input_Name;

    #endregion
    //<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    #region Page Init & Exit (Open/Close DB connections here...)

    protected void PageInit(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }
    //----------------------------------------------------------------------
    protected void PageExit(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    #endregion
    //<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    #region Page Load
    private void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Write(@"Hello #Develop<br>");
        //------------------------------------------------------------------
        if(IsPostBack)
        {
        }
        //------------------------------------------------------------------
    }
    #endregion
    //<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    #region Click_Button_OK

    //----------------------------------------------------------------------
    protected void Click_Button_Ok(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Write( _Button_Ok.Value + " was cklicked!<br>");
    }

    #endregion
    //<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    #region Changed_Input_Name

    //----------------------------------------------------------------------
    protected void Changed_Input_Name(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Write( _Input_Name.Value + " has changed!<br>");
    }

    #endregion
    //<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    #region More...
    #endregion
    //<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    #region Initialize Component

    protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        base.OnInit(e);
    }
    //----------------------------------------------------------------------
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.Load   += new System.EventHandler(Page_Load);
        this.Init   += new System.EventHandler(PageInit);
        this.Unload += new System.EventHandler(PageExit);

        _Button_Ok.ServerClick   += new EventHandler(Click_Button_Ok);
        _Input_Name.ServerChange += new EventHandler(Changed_Input_Name);
    }
    #endregion
    //<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
}
```

}

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parser Error Message: Could not load type 'webmarketing'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23220357/parser-error-message-could-not-load-type-webmarketing)

Comment: Now i am getting, Parser Error
Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately. 

Parser Error Message: Could not load type 'SandLogin.Global'.                                             Source Error: 


Line 1:  <%@ Application Codebehind="Global.cs"
Line 2:   Inherits="SandLogin.Global"
Line 3:  %>

Comment: My server has the following set of files, AssemblyInfo.cs,default.asp,Default.aspx,Default.aspx.cs,Global.asax,Global.asax.cs,SandLogin.css,SandLogin.dll,Web.config