# ASP.NET site error: Could not load type '[SITE]._Default'

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I've written up an ASP.NET / VB site and it's been working fine all through debugging. However, once I publish the site and go to it in browser, I get the error listed in the title.

I've followed a few different sets of instructions to fix the problem, but none of the stuff I've tried seems to be working.

Here is what's at the top of my `Default.aspx` page:

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.vb" Inherits="[SITE]._Default" %>
```

And, the class in my `Default.aspx.vb` file:

```
Public Class _Default
```

I've tried changing "CodeBehind" to "CodeFile" which didn't work and gave me further errors. I'd also like to point out that another project was used as a template and renamed, along with all of the files associated with it, so maybe that's causing an issue? I have no idea. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: There are a few more things to try at [Parser Error Message: Could not load type 'webmarketing'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23220357/parser-error-message-could-not-load-type-webmarketing).

Comment: @AndrewMorton Thanks! I'll check through this when I get a chance.

Comment: @AndrewMorton Unfortunately, none of those solutions worked.

Comment: if you create a blank new page (add->new item->Web form with master page. When you do this, does this new test page work, and you should not have to play with, or in fact modify the first line. In fact messing around with that first line will likely break things.

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal When I try to make the Web Form with Master Page, I can't, because it wants me to select a master page, and I don't have one. Also, what will this accomplish?

Comment: It will accomplish a huge long list of things. First up, if you don't have a master page then we eliminate 50-100 possible issues we don't have to worry about. So we eliminate that huge set of possible issues. And now that we know no master pages are being used? Then does the blank new web page you created then also work? If it does, then we look at first line. And if simple blank new page don't work then we have something rather serious going on here. If a un-messed simple blank page don't work then config or something else is broken. So, does a new blank page work say with "hello" on it?

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal If I add a blank page, and set it to the default ASP.NET startup page, the website still breaks on publish because of the same issue I was having above. Again, it works fine while debugging and running locally, but the moment it gets published, it breaks.

Adding the blank page and setting it to default doesn't... Remove the page that's causing the problems. That other page still causes problems.

Comment: Well, you don't have to set it as the default. When you test, you can type in the URL of that test page. So far we seem to have all pages and everything works fine as debug and a local IIS express site. But when published it don't work. So this suggests the web site config is at fault. But then again if a known new created page don't work, then this points to web site config and not that anything in your application is actually broken.

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal Okay, how would I know if something in the configuration file is messed up or at fault? I'm looking at it right now.

Comment: Well, we would be able to take a spectacular and fantastic guess if a new created page works on your local IIS express from VS, but then now ZERO pages work after being published. If zero and none of the pages EVER work on that site, then we can well start to make the valid conclusion that the web site never worked, never was setup correctly and nothing at all works. So, that information would be quite a revelation, don't you think? So, going down some garden path about messing with ONE header on ONE page when everything is broken would be a WHOPPER of detail you left out, right?

Comment: I shouldn't but I am literally LOL.