# ASPX could not load type

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

When I start my ASP.NET project one of the modules doesn't load. I've tried reloading it and rebuilding the project but it hasn't made any difference. How can I get this to load?

The UI displays a parse error:

[image]

Comment: Any error message, screenshot of UI ?

Comment: @Yegor Androsov The UI displays a parse error. Screenshot added to question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Parser Error Message: Could not load type 'webmarketing'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23220357/parser-error-message-could-not-load-type-webmarketing)

Comment: Thanks. I'll check it this morning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing `CodeBehind` to `CodeFile` resolved this for me.

Answer (score 0):

The code behind file `Error.aspx.cs` must contains the class names `CMSMessage_Error` - but its not find it.

Double check the Name of the class and that this file exist.

Comment: Yes, the class is there.

Comment: @runnerpaul its web application or web site ? - `CodeBehind` or `CodeFile`  - double check this. Maybe change the `CodeBehind` to `CodeFile`

Comment: How can I tell the difference?

Comment: @runnerpaul just change the CodeBehing to CodeFile to see if its works

Comment: I got the same outcome.

Comment: By the way, It was in `Error.aspx` that I changed to CodeFile.